# Как сделать checkbox некликабельным

Tags: javascript, html

Данный фрагмент формирует страницу со скрытым `checkbox`'ом:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="superTag">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />Something
    </div>

    <script>
        var element = document.getElementById("superTag");
        element.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].hidden = "true";
    </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы `checkbox` был, но флажок в него занести нельзя ?

Comment: `disable=true`, `js` тут не нужен

Comment: @ThisMan да, действительно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На js:

```
element.disabled = true;
```

На jQuery:

```
$(element).prop('disabled', true);
```

Использовать на jQuery .attr() для этого не рекомендуется .

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте `disabled` в тег чекбокса:

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled />Something
```